# getchar() keeps returning EOF even after subsequent calls but read() system calls seem to "clear" the stdin. What are the reasons behind this?

Tags: c, file, unix, eof, file-descriptor

```
char buff[1];

int main() {
    int c;
    c = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", c); //output -1

    c = getchar();
    printf("%d\n", c); // output -1

    int res;

    //here I get a prompt for input. What happened to EOF ?
 
    while ((res = read(0, buff, 1)) > 0) { 
        printf("Hello\n");
    }

    while ((res = read(0, buff, 1)) > 0) {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The resulting output showed with commented lines in the code is the result of simply typing <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> (`EOF` on macOS).

I'm a bit confused about the behaviour of `getchar()`, especially when compared to `read`.

1. Shouldn't the `read` system calls inside the `while` loop  also return `EOF`? Why do they prompt the user? Has some sort of `stdin` clear occurred?
2. Considering that `getchar()` uses the `read` system call under the hood how come they behave differently? Shouldn't the `stdin` be "unique" and the `EOF` condition shared?
3. How come in the following code the two `read` system calls return both `EOF` when a <kbd>Ctrl-D</kbd> input is given?

```
    int res;

    while ((res = read(0, buff, 1)) > 0) {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }

    while ((res = read(0, buff, 1)) > 0) {
        printf("Hello\n");
    }
```

I'm trying to find a logic behind all this. Hope that someone could make it clear what `EOF` really is a how it really behaves.

P.S I'm using a Mac OS machine

Comment: stdio keeps state in the `FILE` object, so it remembers when it gets EOF and won't allow reading again until you call `clearerr(stdin)`. `read()` doesn't have any state, so you can read past EOF if new data has become available.

Comment: You could/should demonstrate what @Barmar says by calling `getchar()` after the `read()` calls.  You could also experiment with `clearerr()` too.

Answer (score 3):

Once the *end-of-file indicator* is set for `stdin`, `getchar()` does not attempt to read.

Clear the end-of-file indicator (e.g. `clearerr()` or others) to re-try reading.

> The `getchar` function is equivalent to `getc` with the argument `stdin`.

> The `getc` function is equivalent to `fgetc` ...

> **If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set** and a next character is present, the `fgetc` function obtains that character as an `unsigned char` converted to an `int` and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined).

`read()` still tries to read each time.

---

Note: Reading via a `FILE *`, like `stdin`, does not attempt to read if the end-of-file indicator is set.  Yet even if the *error indicator* is set, a read attempt still occurs.

Comment: To avoid the potential confusion between the range of type `char` and the values returned by `getchar()`, I suggest using *byte* instead of *char* to describe the positive return values of `getchar()`.

Comment: @chqrlie Your suggestion then applies to the C spec - the source of the quotes.  Both _byte_ and `unsigned char`, in C, can mean 8 bits or more.  Yet in common speech, _byte_ implies 8-bit, that is less so with `unsigned char` .  `unsigned char` is the better phrase here.

Comment: The phrase *the `fgetc` function obtains that character* is still somewhat ambiguous as *character* does not properly describe control bytes nor individual bytes of multibyte character encodings `getchar()` is likely to return.  Your wording is more precise and less problematic to this regard than Luis' answer where he does specify a range of 0..255, which is the minimum specified by the C Standard but not the only possibility and where he should use `unsigned char` instead of `char` in many places.

Answer (score 0):

MacOs is a derivative of BSD unix systems.  Its stdio implementation does not come from GNU software and so it is a different implementation.  On EOF, the file descriptor is marked as erroneous when issuing a `read(2)` system call and receiving 0 as the number of characters returned by read, and so, it doesn't `read(2)` it again until the error condition is reset, and this produces the behaviour you observe.  Use `clearerr(stream);` on the `FILE *` descriptor before issuing the next `getchar(3)` call, and everything will be fine.  You can do that with glib also, and then, your program will run the same in either implementation of stdio (glib vs. bsd)

> I'm trying to find a logic behind all this. Hope that someone could make it clear what EOF really is a how it really behaves.

`EOF` is simply a constant (normally it's valued as -1) that is different to any possible `char` value returned by `getchar(3)` (`getchar()` returns an `int` in the interval 0..255, and not a char for this purpose, to extend the range os possible characters with one more to represent the EOF condition, but EOF is not a char)  The end of file condition is so indicated by the getchar family of functions (getchar, fgetc, etc) as the end of file condition is signalled by a `read(2)` return value of 0 (the number of returned characters is zero) which doesn't map as some character.... for that reason, the number of possible chars is extended to an integer and a new value `EOF` is defined to be returned when the end of file condition is reached.  This is compatible with files that have Ctrl-D characters (ASCII EOT or Cntrl-D, decimal value 4) and not representing an END OF FILE condition (when you read an ASCII EOT from a file it appears as a normal character of decimal value 4)

The unix tty implementation, on the other side, allows on line input mode to use a special character (Ctrl-D, ASCII EOT/END OF TRANSMISSION, decimal value 4) to indicate and end of stream to the driver.... this is a special character, like ASCII CR or ASCII DEL (that produce line editing in input before feeding it to the program) in that case the terminal just prepares all the input characters and allows the application to read them (if there's none, none is read, and you got the end of file)  So think that the Cntrl-D is *only special* in the unix tty driver and only when it is working in canonical mode (line input mode).  So, finally, there are only two ways to input data to the program in line mode:

- pressing the RETURN key (this is mapped by the terminal into ASCII CR, which the terminal translates into ASCII LF, the famous `'\n'` character)  *and the ASCII LF character is input to the program*
- pressing the Ctrl-D key.  this makes the terminal to grab all that was keyed in upto this moment and send it to the program (without adding the Ctrl-D itself)  *and no character is added to the input buffer, what means that, if the input buffer was empty, nothing is sent to the program* and the `read(2)` call reads effectively zero characters from the buffer.

To unify, in every scenario, the `read(2)` system call normally blocks into the kernel until one or more characters are available.... only at end of file, it unblocks and returns zero characters to the program.  THIS SHOULD BE YOUR END OF FILE INDICATION.  Many programs read an incomplete buffer (less than the number of characters you passed as parameter) before a true END OF FILE is signalled, and so, almost every program does another read to check if that was an incomplete read or indeed it was an end of file indication.

Finally, what if I want to input a Cntrl-D character as itself to a file.... there's another special character in the tty implementation that allows you to escape the special behaviour on the special character this one precedes.  In today systems, that character is by default Ctrl-V, so if you want to enter a special character (even ?Ctrl-V) you have to precede it with Ctrl-V, making entering Ctrl-D into the file to have to input Ctrl-V + Ctrl-D.

Comment: Aside: `EOF` ... "is different to any possible char value returned by getchar(3)" is more like "is different to any possible _unsigned char_ value returned by getchar(3) _and is negative_.

Comment: as the spacification says, _getchar() returns an int value in the range 0..255 or `EOF`_, but it doesn't force it to be negative... It is, in the majority of implementations, and that is compatible with the error return value of any system call.  But IMHO ANSI C doesn't specify `EOF` to be negative.  That's a minor point, indeed, and defining `EOF` to be a positive value (like 256, for example) is somewhat weird and will probably break legacy software.

Comment: "But IMHO ANSI C doesn't specify EOF to be negative." --> "`EOF` which expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value" C17dr § 7.21.1 3

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica, getchar doesn’t return unsigned values. It returns a value in the range 0..255 or EOF. No special value is defined in the standard for EOF constant, but almost all implementations use -1 as the value for EOF. nobody talks about unsigned values here, as the return type is int